# Remove horizontal line from geom_histogram in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I would like to plot a histogram with some text off to the righthand side, but the x axis (or possibly the lower part of the histogram) extends out to the text. How can I remove this line?

```
library(tibble)  
library(ggplot2)  
library(dplyr)

my_label <- "text"

p <- rnorm(10000) %>%
  as_tibble(.) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = value)) +
    geom_histogram(color = 'black', fill = 'grey70', bins = 30) +
    annotate(geom = 'text', x = 15, y = 1500, label = my_label,
             hjust = 1, size = 3, color = "#cc0000") +
    theme_void()
```

Comment: There’s no need to use `.` if it’s the first argument, and indeed it’s kind of discouraged. So instead write `rnorm(10000) %>% as_tibble() %>% ggplot(aes(x = value)) …`.

Comment: I don't believe it is discouraged, but rather a matter of personal preference (http://style.tidyverse.org/pipes.html). I prefer to keep them for teaching purposes. Do you have a link to anything saying it is discouraged?

Answer (score 1):

```
A quick hack to rid your plot of the x-axis line

rnorm(10000) %>%
  as_tibble() -> dat

dat %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value)) +
  geom_histogram(color = 'black', fill = 'grey70') +
  annotate(geom = 'text', x = 15, y = 1500, label = my_label,
           hjust = 1, size = 3, color = "#cc0000") +
  theme_void() +
  geom_histogram(data = tibble(value=1:15), color = 'white')
```